# ETABS 2016 VBA SetOConcrete_1 assigns only the last Fc value for all definitions

Tags: vba, excel, api

I'm working on an Excel VBA module that supplies certain data to ETABS 2016, part of the code is to define multiple material properties through using API methods `SetMaterial` and `SetOConcrete_1`.
The effective part of the code is this

```
    'Values:-
    'Val(0)=label, Val(1)=Fc', Val(2)=E, Vals(3)=StrainAtFc, Val(4)=UltimateStrain, Val(5)=PoisonRatio, Val(6)=Thermal Coef
    'Val(7) = UnitWeight
    For i = 0 To iCount - 1
    .
    .
    SOME LONG CODE TO RETRIEVE DATA TO A DYNAMIC ARRAY OF VARIANTS CALLED "VAL"
    .
    .
    With myModel.PropMaterial
    MsgBox Val(0) & " " & Val(1) & " " & i 'debug line to display input values for label and FC'
    ret = .SetMaterial(Val(0), eMatType_Concrete)
    ret = .SetOConcrete_1(Val(0), Val(1), False, 0, 2, 4, Val(3), Val(4), -0.1)
    ret = .SetWeightAndMass(Val(0), 1, Val(7))
    ret = .SetMPIsotropic(Val(0), Val(2), Val(5), Val(6))
    End With
    Next i
```

I've even added a debugging part to display the values of interest, per one definition, two definitions, and so on, this part is

```
    'Debugging part
     If i >= 0 Then
         On Error GoTo 0
         Err.Raise (2)
     End If
    'End of Debugging part
```

and then, I change `i >= 0` to `i >= 1` and to `i >= 2` to display the needed number of iterations .

The debugging part always displays the correct and needed values of `Val(0)`(the material's Name) and `Val(1)`(the material's Fc) for every iteration,
for example, the values for every iteration are:-

1- Iteration no.1: `Val(0) = "C35"`, `Val(1) = 35000`, i = 0

2- Iteration no.2: `Val(0) = "C37"`, `Val(1) = 37000`, i = 1

3- Iteration no.3: `Val(0) = "C38"`, `Val(1) = 38000`, i = 2

and Then, what happens in ETABS is the following:-

1- With `i >= 0` I get one iteration and one material definition of "C35", "C35" has Fc = 35MPa [Correct Result]

2- With `i >= 1` I get two iterations and two material definitions of "C35" and "C37", but all of them have Fc = 37 MPa [Wrong Result]

3- With `i >= 2` I get three iterations and three material definitions of "C35", "C37" and "C38", but all of them have Fc = 38 MPa [Wrong Result]

---

So, How Can the supplied values of the material's name and Fc to `SetOConcrete_1` be different at every iteration and ETABS just ignores all that work and just supplies only the last Fc value to all materials?!

Answer (score 0):

Is the ETABS API taking the value you supply it as a reference? That's what it seems like based on your explanation.

```
Public Sub Temp()
    'In order to use early-binding Dictionary you need to set a
    'reference in Tools>References>"Microsoft Scripting Runtime"
    Dim foo As Dictionary
    Set foo = New Dictionary

    Dim bar As Range
    Set bar = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

    bar.Value2 = "Original"

    foo.Add "1", bar.Value2
    foo.Add "2", bar

    bar.Value2 = "Changed"

    Debug.Print foo("1")
    Debug.Print foo("2")
End Sub
```

If you go through this example you'll notice that when an item is added with `.Value2`, value type, it doesn't change. When it's fed in as a `Range`, reference type, it will change.

You may have a different outcome if you extract each value in the `Val` variable into their respective type before feeding them in.

```
Dim label As String
label = Val(0)

Dim Fc As Long
Fc = Val(1)

Dim strainAtFc As Long
strainAtFc = Val(3)

Dim ultimateStrain As Long
ultimateStrain = Val(4)

Dim poisonRatio As Long
poisonRatio = Val(5)

Dim thermalCoefficient As Long
thermalCoefficient = Val(6)

Dim unitWeight As Long
unitWeight = Val(7)
```

***Note that `Val` is also a member of VBA.Conversion and could cause issues if it isn't `Dim`d.

Comment: `Val` is already `Dim`d before the loop, then I did what you told me by extracting `Val`'s values to variables, one time all of them where Variants, and the other with their respective types. At both times ,the error affects the assignment of `Fc`, `strainAtFc`, `ultimateStrain`, `poisonRatio`, `thermalCoefficient` ... However, the good news that `label` and `unitWeight` were supplied correctly.

Comment: Also, To add to the **partially** good news, in order to supply values _correctly_, at every iteration (material definition) I must go to the running ETABS itself and see the material's values from the ETABS's GUI. Which is of course a weird way. But sadly the problem still exists if I didn't see values from ETABS during the looping process.